# What's the difference between --unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs and --allow-shlib-undefined flags

Tags: linker, ld, elf

What is the difference between the following linker (ld) flags:

--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs

--allow-shlib-undefined

?

And as a follow up what's the difference between unresolved symbols and undefined symbols in this nomenclature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The linker option:

```
--unresolved-symbols=method
```

lets you specify any of 4 different criteria (*method*) for the linker
to report or ignore unresolved symbol references in a linkage. [The manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html)
says:

> --unresolved-symbols=method
>
> Determine how to handle unresolved symbols. There are four possible values for ‘method’:
>
> ‘ignore-all’
>
> ```
>    Do not report any unresolved symbols.
> ```
>
> ‘report-all’
>
> ```
>    Report all unresolved symbols. This is the default.
> ```
>
> ‘ignore-in-object-files’
>
> ```
>    Report unresolved symbols that are contained in shared libraries, but ignore them if they come from regular object files.
> ```
>
> ‘ignore-in-shared-libs’
>
> ```
>    Report unresolved symbols that come from regular object files, but ignore them if they come from shared libraries. This can be useful when creating a dynamic binary and it is known that all the shared libraries that it should be referencing are included on the linker’s command line.
> ```
>
> **The behaviour for shared libraries on their own can also be controlled by the --[no-]allow-shlib-undefined option.**
>
> Normally the linker will generate an error message for each reported unresolved symbol but the option --warn-unresolved-symbols can change this to a warning.

As the sentence I've emphasised indicates, the linker option:

```
--allow-shlib-undefined
```

is just a shorter way of saying:

```
--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs
```

There is no difference in meaning between `undefined` and `unresolved` in this context:
the suggestion of a difference is just part of the cruft of this ancient tool.

Comment: Thank you very much. No the "flag" word in the original post was bad editing. Sorry, I've corrected it.

Comment: @listerreg Np, removed from answer.